# prove that a black-box multivariable problem is convex or concave

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

First of all I am not mathematician.

I want to solve a very complex black box function with several constraints having to do with electrical power flows in electrical grids. At the moment I use the Nelder-Mead method.

Normally similar problems are solved using interior point (which by definition proves to find global optimums), but I have no interior point implementation or library available to use in the program that I developed for the purpose.

Since Nelder-Mead only finds local minimums, I would like somehow prove that the problem itself is convex, so when I find a local minimum, it is actually the global minimum.

I would like to know if such thing is possible or if it is absurd to try.

[Edit]

The function I optimize is the amount of overloading of branch elements in electrical grids plus other technical constraints that vary depending on the grid situation.
The black-box function is the load flow problem, which is a set of non-linear equations. (So yes, it is not strctly a black-box function, but the formulation becomes too complex) Usually the same kind of problem (called Optimal Power Flow) is solved formulating the power flow equations into an interior point solver (which I cannot afford, and that is why I am using free implementation of other methods)

Best regards,
Santi.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the fitness function is band limited (i.e. smoothly rolling instead of spiky)?  If not, the optimum could be in an arbitrary small basin and you will not be able to find it (via black box methods) without evaluating the objective function over the entire configuration space.

Comment: The equations are the Power flow ones (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-flow_study) where the input is the apparent power (P + jQ) and the output is the voltage (V<Theta). Said this, the objective function I minimize is very tricky because it includes electrical devices controls that can switch on/off, so the objective function can be spiky but it is smooth for most of the input. And due to this I am not confident using nelder-mead. I have been using genetic algorithms, but they are very slow in comparison, and both achieve results within the bounds I need.

Comment: You should add this information to your question by editing it.

Comment: The line "the inherent problems of fractality in the basins of attraction of the underlying iterative map" from the page you reference strongly suggests the optimum does lie in arbitrarily small basins of attraction.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes that would be for the load flow itself, but my function uses the load flow solution as an input variable of the function I try to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is black-box one, then by definition you have no access to its explicit form and so no way to asses its convexity or concavity.

But since you mention interior-point methods (IPM), I wonder whether your function is really a black-box one: IPM are second-order methods, i.e. they require the Hessian. I guess some can use Hessian approximation and even gradient approximation, but then you loose all the advantages.

Moreover, when you mention global optimality, well this follows from convexity assumptions, not by IPM itself. In fact there are IPM designed for non-convex problem. For instance you can give a look to the Ipopt solver.

So when you say people usually use IPM, I suspect that you have a convex problem in closed form that you can solve using one of the many available solvers, for instance MOSEK (ok I am biased, it's the company I work for). Most of them provide trial or academic licenses.

If you stick with bloack-box or derivative free methods, I might suggest you to search for NOMAD.

Comment: Well my function is not strictly a black box, to use IPM, I can make the formulation, because what I have is a non-linear set of equations, that right now I use as a black box due to its complexity.  Indeed, MOSEK, GUROBI, CPLEX, etc.. are great comercial solvers, but all of them are out of my budget right now.

Comment: Ok, but I will suggest you to use the convex formulation anyway. If you can use a trial or academic license, give it a try. Otherwise there are other tools like cvxopt or ipopt which are free.